# Customize DataFrame.compare function for float

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I can use Dataframe.compare function to compare 2 dataframes with same shape and column labels. It would return NaN for the cell that have the same value in both dataframes so you can easily identify which cell have difference. E.g.

```
    df1           df2                df1.compare(df2)
   A  B          A  B                  A           B
0  10 20       0 10 20           self  other  self  other
1  11 22       1 11 23   ->   0  NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
                              1  NaN   NaN     22     23
```

However, when it compares dataframe with FLOAT, only tiny difference makes pandas thinks that they are different hence not marking it as NaN. Example below (because of space I cannot type .0099999999..., but I hope you get the idea). How can I make DataFrame.compare to use something like np.isclose so I can set the tolerance when comparing 2 floats?

```
    df3           df4                        df3.compare(df4)
    A     B           A      B                A               B
0  1.11 1.21   0 1.1099 1.2099         self   other    self  other
1  1.12 1.22   1 1.1199 1.2001  ->  0  1.11   1.1099   1.21  1.2099
                                    1  1.12   1.1199   1.22  1.2001
```

My aim is to have an output similar to the original output having (self, other) columns and showing mostly NaN and let me spot the differences quickly. E.g.

```
         df3.compare(df4)
          A               B
   self  other    self   other
0  NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN
1  NaN   NaN       1.22  1.2001
```

I tried reading the source of DataFrame.compare but it calls super().compare, which I don't know where it leads to ... Should I be overriding one of those comparison function like `__ge__`, `__le__` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for join both first with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) by `np.isclose`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns,['self','other']])
m = np.isclose(df1, df2)

df = (pd.concat([df1.mask(m), df2.mask(m)], axis=1, keys=('self','other'))
        .swaplevel(axis=1)
        .reindex(mux, axis=1))
print (df)
     A           B      
  self other  self other
0  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  NaN   NaN  22.0  23.0
```

Comment: I edited my question hoping that it is clearer to any reader. My question is specifically on how to modify the behavior when DataFrame.compare comparing floats.

Comment: @Gary But it is not possible, because no parameter in `df.compare` for do it. So added different solution.